# How can I create a bootable USB Stick with a Linux distro for my M1 Mac?

Tags: linux, usb

I am searching the web since days because I am trying to create a bootable Kali USB for my M1 MacBookPro.

Last attempts were f.e.:

https://medium.com/macoclock/install-kali-linux-live-usb-with-persistence-using-macos-b1574c996491

https://youtu.be/mDRbTHCoj8U

But it is not working.

I guess the problem is that the M1 Mac not recognizes the USB as bootable but I am not sure :(

Has somebody of you been already able to create a bootable USB Stick for the M1 Mac with a Linux Distribution ?

Comment: There aren't any bootable Linux Live-USB's for Apples new hardware yet to my knowledge. M1 based Macs are so different form anything else that it is going to take a while for the Linux developers  to be able to write the necessary drivers and special boot-loaders that are required. (And Apple isn't helping either. They are very secretive about a lot of technical details, which makes it very hard for the Linux developers.)

Comment: This question should be revisited.

Answer (score 2):

Those instructions won't work on your system. They were written for "Intel" Macs – i.e. with CPUs supporting the Intel x86_64 (aka amd64) architecture, like most PCs use. The M1 is **completely different** from those.

1. M1 and other "Apple Silicon" CPUs use the ARM64 architecture – they cannot run x86_64 software. You would need an ARM-compatible distro image. (If the downloads page just says "64-bit", it's almost always x86_64.)
2. The boot process of Apple Silicon systems is different from not just from UEFI PCs, but even from Intel Macs. It doesn't look for the same files or partitions, and it doesn't use the same type of bootloader. (According to its docs, the bootloader has to be shaped like a "XNU kernel" – i.e. be a macOS kernel or pretend it's one.)
3. **Most importantly:** Linux, in general, cannot run on M1 yet. The entire *system* architecture of the M1 is rather nonstandard, even compared to other ARM systems – PCI works differently, USB works differently, interrupts work differently, etc.

   There is [an effort](https://asahilinux.org/) to write all necessary Linux drivers for the M1 series Macs, but while it mostly works on developers' machines it'll still take a while for it to reach distro releases. For example, as of this post, the Linux patches necessary to support M1's PCI Express controllers were submitted *literally yesterday.* Proper GPU support is expected to still take a while.

Comment: Thanks for your answers

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I installed a Linux distro under Parallels now. But what are the Pros and Cons to run it like that vs. run it natively on a "windows" notebook?